# Multiple if structure in a php function

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to run a php script which would return the name of a specific icon, depending on the day.

I have added this special method which computes the Easter day (Sunday).

Now, I have added a special case for today (17.08), just to test my algorithm. However, my $returnValue does not return the icon that I would like (i.e. assets/icons/logo_halloween.png) ... I know it's not halloween yet, but come on ;-)

I am probably doing something wrong here with my structure of the if's. Would be glad if you could assist me on this. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
function getIconFileName()
{
$iconPath = "assets/icons/";
$returnValue = ".";    


// gets current year and stores it in a variable
$year = date('Y');

// Calcul des dates variables (Pâques)

// gets the Easter Sunday
$date_Easter_Sunday = easter_date($year);

if ((date('m') == (date('m', $date_Easter_Sunday))) && (date('d') == (date('d', $date_Easter_Sunday))))
{
    // Dimanche de Pâques
    $returnValue = $iconPath . "logo.png";
}

elseif ((date('m') == 08) && (date('d') == 17))                 
 // ---> It looks like my code never returns this value (logo_halloween.png) <----
{
    $returnValue = $iconPath . "logo_halloween.png";
}

// Calcul des dates fixes

elseif ((date('m') == 01) && (date('d') == 01)) 
{
    // Premier jour de l'an
    $returnValue = $iconPath . "logo.png";
}

elseif ((date('m') == 03) && (date('d') == 21)) 
{
    // Premier jour du printemps
    $returnValue = $iconPath . "logo.png";
}

else
{
    // Ceci est un jour normal
    $returnValue = $iconPath . "logo.png";
}

echo "Path to icon : " . $returnValue . "<br>";

return $returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And is my description at the very beginning not useful ?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include [...] **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** [...]

Comment: replace `" +1 day"` with `" next monday"` and `" -2 day"` with `" last friday"` maybe that helps

Comment: OK, done. I trimmed the code as much as I could. Thanks

Comment: Shorten this: `strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_tmp)) . " +1 day");` to `strtotime($date_tmp . " +1 day");` too

Comment: And `((date('m') == (date('m', $date_Easter_Sunday))) && (date('d') == (date('d', $date_Easter_Sunday))))` to `((date('m d') == (date('m d', $date_Easter_Sunday)))`

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions. OK, thanks - will do so. But the problem is really where I put my marker (on the date of today)

Comment: Finally chane `08` to just `8` and it works, or lets say integers in PHP dont need zeros fill from left.  just 1 not 01 and so on.

Comment: Indeed it works well, thanks - so if I follow your example which I really prefer, that would be '((date('m d') == (date('8 17')))' ?

Comment: Use last line from @Drkdra answer or `((date('m d') == '08 17') `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
elseif ((date('m') == 08) && (date('d') == 17))
```

Change to

```
elseif ((date('m') == 8) && (date('d') == 17))
```

And it will work. When compare `date('m')` which return the string `'08'` with an integer, `08`, php convert the string `'08'` to integer `8`, and the result of `8 == 08` expression is `false`.

Or better:

```
elseif (date('m/d') == '08/17')
```

Answer (score 1):

change it to:

```
if ((date('m') == 8) && (date('d') == 17))                 
{
    $returnValue = $iconPath . "logo_halloween.png";
}
```

Why test this:

```
if (("08" == 08))                 
{
   echo "OK 08 == 08";
}

if ((08=="08"))                 
{
    echo "OK 08 == 08";
}
```

You will see no OK on screen. Both tests fail.
Its all about TypeCasting!!